# AUCTeX does not recognize texlive installation

Tags: auctex

I am running Emacs 25 on Kubuntu 17.10.

I have a texlive installation in:

> /home/user/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux

`echo $PATH` produces:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux

But out of this, /home/user/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64slinux was added by hand in my ~/.zshrc.

So, I added the following line to my ~/.emacs:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/home/user/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux")
```

Now, `(getenv "PATH")` shows the full path as mentioned above.

And yet when I try to compile a .tex file using C-c C-a, it produces an error:

> AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution.

What is happening? How do I get AUCTeX to compile?

Comment: What's the output of `(getenv "PATH")`?

Comment: @matteol I am surprized! It is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` The last part was added in my `~/.zshrc` by hand. I think that is the cause of the error. How do I set it right?

Comment: I don't know but if you add details about your OS an emacs version maybe someone else can help you

Comment: @matteol Done that. Edited the question so all can see.

Comment: Emacs doesn't read shell rc files on its own by default, so customizing your `PATH` there won't affect what's set in emacs.

Comment: A change in .profile should be visible to every program after a logout and login

Comment: @matteol I made the necessary change (added path to emacs path) but still I am not able to compile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have two possible solutions:

a) use the package exec-path-from-shell to add your path in emacs init.el file

b) add/modify this code to your auctex initialization in init.el file (this is mine for mac):

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/Library/TeX/texbin:"
                         (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin")
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `PATH` variable in `.profile` not in `.zshrc` and remove the change in `.emacs`. Logout and login again.