# emacs with auctex on win 10: Preview pdflatex fails

Tags: auctex

First of all, I'm a beginner to emacs, who has just begun the tutorial and reading the manuals. Therefore kindly bear with me if the given details may be somewhat lacking.

1. On win 10, I have installed the latest version of the complete Tex Live-environment (default path C:/texlive); I can create and preview *.tex-files with the included editor Texworks  without issues. (if relevant: Ghostscript 9.56.1 is installed in C:/program files/gs)
2. I would like to use Gnu-Emacs as LaTex-editor instead. Thanks to the manuals, I have managed to install the latest version 27.2 into C:/user/documents/emacs) and via ELPA the latest version of the required package auctex-package. Everything seems to have installed fine.
3. I have loaded the included circ.tex. All attempts to create/ preview a pdf-file - I have really tried each and every of the command-options in the preview-menu - fail.
4. I have made a screenshot, can it be added it here?

Error-message translated freely from German: 'The command "pdflatex" has either not been spelled correctly or cannot be found. Tex output ended as expected with Code 1 etc. LateX: LateX found no preview images.'

So i suspect that Emacs/ auctex probably cannot find pdflatex.exe by itself in c:/texlive. And if so, that I have to help them find it by somehow loading the required path(s) into one of the Emacs ini-files (.init.el and/ or .emacs)?

In case more information should be needed and if there is a way to post the screenshot, please let me know.

Thank you very kindly!

Comment: Use the command window to find out ```where texbin``` is and add it to your path. Then see this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37291/auctex-does-not-recognize-texlive-installation/37296#37296 how to add it in emacs. That page shows how to for linux/Mac, but you should write it for win 10.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't try to adjust the `PATH` in your Emacs init file and change it within your OS instead.  There are plenty of guides on the net, I'm quoting from [this site](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html).

> **Windows 10**
>
> 1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
> 2. Click the **Advanced system settings** link.
> 3. Click **Environment Variables**. In the section System Variables find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click **Edit**. If
>    the `PATH` environment variable does not exist, click `New`.
> 4. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the `PATH` environment variable. Click **OK**.
>    Close all remaining windows by clicking **OK**.

Add `C:/program files/gs` and `C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32` also to `PATH` so Emacs and AUCTeX can find the binaries.

I also suggest you add `C:/user/documents/emacs/bin` to `PATH` in case you want to start Emacs from a CLI.

Finally, you can define and/or set the variable `HOME` to a directory of your choice and put your init file there.  This will make Emacs store it files (from ELPA for instance) under `%HOME%/.emacs.d/elpa`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both very much, that worked like a charm! Arash: I just realized after another night of wild googling that I had already literally 'messed' with the Win-environment variables, but tragically overlooked to append the /win32 to C:/texlive/2022/bin  So once again, the devil has proven to lurk in the details. ;-) Happy to have asked in the right forum, all have a pleasant day!

Comment: It sounds like the problem was pilot error (an oversight). If you don't think the question and answer are likely to help others then maybe delete the question. But of course keep it if you think it might help.